# Is This Ad Hominem?

Tags: phrase-usage

If I say to a lawyer

> It is all the more ironic that with all that legal knowledge at your disposal you have not come up with a single logically coherent argument or couter-argument. I do not know whether your clients should laugh or cry.

Given that the first statement is true, does the statement constitute ad hominem?

Comment: What do you think? What research did you do about the meaning of "ad hominem"?

Comment: This is an interesting borderline case. The words are describing the person making the argument and not about the argument itself. But it is not fallacious because it is about the _ability_ to make an argument. Since a lawyer is an expert in legal arguments, it is calling into question the expert's abilities which is definitely relevant. (e.g. it is relevant to say that a doctor is a bad one because his patients keep dying but not because he kicked a dog).

Comment: For what is said to be a good argument, there needs to be support for the statement, otherwise it is just an unsubstantiated judgement (and a fallacy , just not ad hominem).

Comment: This might be better asked at philosophy.SE though as it is not particular to English.

Comment: It's definitely not *ad hominem* if it's in a discussion of whether the lawyer is qualified to undertake some job (though even then it's extremely discourteous.)  I would say that it is *ad hominem* if this is part of your rebuttal of an argument he is presenting, however.  (Simply saying "you have not presented a counter-argument", without "all the legal knowledge", without "cannot come up with", and without the second sentence would not be AH, though.)

Comment: @Mitch: I have addressed your second comment by the clause "given that the second statement is true". Do you agree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's *ad hominem*. While it doesn't go into detail, it appears to be stating that none of the lawyer's arguments are logically coherent. This is a statement about the substance of the arguments themselves, not about the lawyer's character.

However, by making such a general statement about the lawyer's arguments, and referring to all the resources he had at his disposal, which should have allowed him to do better, it's also making a statement about the lawyer's abilities. This is a valid form of argument.

In other words, what it's saying is that he's a poor lawyer because he can't come up with coherent arguments. An ad hominem attack would be to say that the arguments are incoherent because he's a bad lawyer.

Comment: I agree with this. It is an assertion (that may be either true or false), dressed up with sarcastic irony. Of course, if the assertion is correct, it should be milked it for all it is worth.

Comment: @Mick And the OP states that the assertion is true.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it is. In this statement, you are not actually addressing any of the lawyer's arguments, you are saying that the lawyer himself is incapable of forming a coherent argument, thus attacking his character rather than his arguments or actions, which is the definition of an ad hominem attack. It is also a very mean thing to say.

> [***Ad hominem***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ad_hominem)
>
> (Latin for 'to the man' or 'to the person')
>
> Short for *argumentum ad hominem*, is a logical fallacy in which an argument is rebutted by attacking the character, motive, or other attribute of the person making the argument, or persons associated with the argument, rather than attacking the substance of the argument itself." (Wikipedia)

Note, however, that this statement could very easily go from ad hominem to not, simply by changing the direction of the statement from the lawyer's ability to form the arguments to the arguments themselves; as you said in a comment below, to say "you have not" rather than "you can not" and give examples of why his arguments are not coherent.

Comment: I disagree. The first sentence appears to be saying that none of the arguments were valid, so they're attacking his arguments, not his character.

Comment: The French Wikipedia article [Argumentum ad hominem](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argumentum_ad_hominem) contradicts the english version, stating that such arguments is refering to the previous acts or saying of the person. When denigrating the person itself, without any link to the subject, it is an [Argumentum ad personam](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argumentum_ad_personam).

Comment: @Graffito *ad personam* doesn't seem to get used in English. The distinction that the French seem to be making is whether the target of the attack is the conclusions or the person himself, not what the basis of the attack is.

Comment: @Barmar: From this [source](http://rozenbergquarterly.com/issa-proceedings-1998-the-argument-ad-hominem-in-an-interactional-perspective/): As emphasized in historical surveys of the notion, the "ad hominem" refers to various argumentative phenomena that have to be sorted out before proceeding to any further reflection. There is a distinction between arguments "ex concessis" based on propositions conceded by the adversary, and proofs or refutation focussing on the person rather than on the matter of the case. To avoid confusion, the latter has sometimes been called "argumentum ad personam".

Comment: @Barmar, as a standalone statement, this does not actually address the arguments at all, but rather the lawyer's ability to form the arguments. If the statement addressed why the lawyer's arguments were not coherent, it would not be ad hominem, but it does not.

Comment: @Graffito It seems that in English, we use *ad hominem* for what that describes as *ad personam*.

Comment: @Barmar: I agree with you and I think that in English as in French "Ad hominem" generally covers both arguments based on previous sayings of the adversary (Ad hominem) and those focusing more on the person of adversary than on the object of the controversy (Ad personam). It seems that only purists make such distinction

Comment: I have already stated "while" --- I have changed the word to "given" --- "the first statement is true". So taken as a fact that he can not form a coherent argument, why do you say it is an attack on his character rather than his argument? Maybe "you can not" is ambiguous. If I change it to "you have not come up with a single logically coherent argument", would you say it is not ad hominem?

Comment: @Hans, yes, if you say 'you have not' rather than 'you can not', it is not ad hominem. My answer was posted before you made your edits and I have not had access to a computer in the meantime. Your statement would be particularly strong if you gave examples as to why his arguments were not coherent, but the key here is to direct it at the comments and not the man. I am currently on my phone, but I will edit my answer once I have access to a computer again (just posting a comment on this tiny keyboard is frustrating enough!)

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not.
[Oxford Online](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/ad_hominem) defines ad hominem:

> (of an argument or reaction) directed against a person rather than the position they are maintaining:

The example:

> It is all the more ironic that with all that legal knowledge at your disposal you can not come up with a single logically coherent argument or couter-argument. I do not know whether your clients should laugh or cry.

This quote does not refer to any reaction or argument made by the lawyer.

Because the quote does not argue any position, it is not an argument and is not a candidate to be considered *ad hominem.*

It is simply a personal attack.  It makes no contribution to support or to disagree with any statement.  It is useless fluff, not a fallacious argument.

Comment: "does not refer to any statement or argument made by the lawyer." It seems like it refers to *all* of them, claiming that none of them are logically coherent.

Comment: Unless you think it's saying that the lawyer didn't come up with any arguments at all.

Comment: One can argue that it disparages the lawyer, over and above the merits of his argument, and that would make it AH.

Comment: @HotLicks: Why do you say it is over and above the merits of his argument, given the statement "given that the first statement is true"?

Comment: @Hans - Because saying "your argument has no merit" is not AH, but saying "you're an idiot and your argument has no merit" *is* AH, even if the argument has no merit.

Comment: @HotLicks: I have stated "given that the second statement is true". It is irrelevant what the detailed argument is for our judgement. The fact is his argument is logically contradictory. As such the first sentence is a statement of that fact --- instead of a conclusion of a derivational process carried out by the sentence. Do you agree that this is not AH? To make it even clearer, I would change, as you suggested in your above comment "can not" to "have not", but keep the second sentence. Does it make you change your judgment?

Comment: @Hans - If you say "you're an idiot", that is an AH attack, regardless of the truth of anything else you utter in the same breath.

Comment: @HotLicks: First you should answer whether my edited statement is AH. That is the issue here. Please do not sidetrack. Second, regarding "you're an idiot", for that to fit the definition of AH, it has to be in a deductive form. So do you mean to say "... . Therefore you are an idiot."? But that is not too off the mark given the condition. So you can not say that is AH.

Comment: As recently edited, it's borderline.  And any time you tell your opponent in a debate that he's an idiot, that is AH.

Comment: Wait.. I thought a personal attack _is_ an ad hominem. You're saying because personal attacks are not in themselves arguments, which is part of the definition.  THat's not how it works. A personal attack _is_ used as an argument, as possibly here when it says 'You have these personal characteristics, therefore you are wrong'. That's an ad hominem argument. It may be fallacious or not, depending if the personal characteristics are relevant to the wrongness.

Comment: e.g. if an expert witness, as a doctor, says that the victim's heart was on the right side of his body, it is entirely relevant to point out that the witness is not a cardiologist but a PhD in mathematics.

Comment: @HotLicks If you tell your opponent that he is an idiot, but you don't tell him he is wrong, you have not made an AH argument.  You've just called him a name without advancing your argument. That is the distinction I am making.  If you don't say (or at least imply) that his argument is wrong, then it isn't an ad hominem argument.

Comment: @Mitch I don't see the "therefore you are wrong" part.  Can you quote it?

Comment: @jejorda2 The context of all this is in an argument, right? It's understood. Sure, running down the street and yelling 'You bastard' is not an attempt an an argument. But saying that to a lawyer, is an ad hominem. But if the lawyer is prosecuting a child custody battle and the lawyer's parents were not married at the time of his birth, then that could be a very relevant bias.

Comment: @Mitch I don't see that context.  If I sit next to my lawyer at our kids' basketball game and speak the quote to him, it makes perfect sense. It doesn't refer to any assertion he has made.  If there were a context, the quote could be part of an AH argument.  But the quote as it is written has no context.